# reading shp files to geopandas to dictionary with the same name

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, geopandas

I'm walking through a directory structure finding all files with the .shp extension and storing them in a dictionary. However, some files are named the same, how do I store files of the same name in a dictionary without overwriting? Appending the file structure to the name would be acceptable in this case. How is that done?

Current 'working' code:

```
def get_all_shp(mydir):
    # layers = []
    data = {}
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(mydir):
        for file in files:
            try:
                if file.endswith(".shp"):
                    shp = os.path.join(root, file)
                    # layers.append(shp)
                    path = root + "/" + file
                    # print("path: " + path)
                    data[file] = gpd.read_file(path)

            except:
                pass
```

Comment: I've tried the geopands.Dataframe.rename() but as I understand it this is for column renaming?

Comment: This solved the issue `data[path] = gpd.read_file(path)`

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_all_shp(mydir):
    # layers = []
    data = {}
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(mydir):
        for file in files:
            try:
                if file.endswith(".shp"):
                    shp = os.path.join(root, file)
                    # layers.append(shp)
                    path = root + "/" + file
                    # print("path: " + path)
                    data[path] = gpd.read_file(path)
            except:
                pass
```